# Regex works in other engines but not Java Pattern/Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I can't figure out why this regex doesn't work, I've tested it in php and other regex engines where it works fine and matches ",AA,".

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^|,)AA(,|$)");

Matcher m = p.matcher("A,B,AA,C,D");

//assigns as false  
boolean matches = m.matches();
```

Side note:  I have a split/array binary search method for doing an IN_SET / NOT_IN_SET search against the string.  This is just an example I need to get working before implementing regex as another comparing option.

Comment: `(^|,)` could be re-written as `^,?`, right? Or this part of a longer string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`matches()` validates the entire string. You want to use `find()` instead.

From the API:

> #### `matches()`
>
> Attempts to match the entire region against the pattern.
>
> -- [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29)

and:

> #### `find()`
>
> Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.
>
> -- [http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

`Matcher` matches the *entire region* against the pattern. Use `find()`.